# the_time('M') does not work in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I need to get months like Jan, Feb in Wordpress. I have tried:

```
the_time('M')
the_time('b')
the_date('M')
get_the_date('M')
```

But I get no output at all. All other formats except M work, and since it is printing the value right away I can not format it afterwards.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual output, nothing? Different format? Wrong date?

Comment: Nothing... Every other date format character works... not M

Comment: What do you get with something like `the_time('M Y')` or `the_time('Y M')`
`

Comment: [`the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) - M *should* work, see as well [Formatting Date and Time (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) - Maybe it's a [bug in wordpress](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/)?

Comment: @Wesley it outputs just year ... 2011 that is all

Comment: @hakre i know it should work, and i have read above since i am using these functions correctly... but it does not work... even thought it is basically standard wordpress installation with more or less standard template, no modification and so on ... so what i am asking how to overcome this and get what i ant in different ways...

Comment: @XFaktor: Which Wordpress version are you using?

Comment: Does it work if you use M in the date on the Administrative section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_time('M')` and `the_date('M')` do same thing and working 
Other 2 maybe didn't work because i never used it try :

```
<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> & <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to run this? Remember that the_time() has to be used within the Loop, otherwise it won't have anything to print/return: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time

Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the other formats supposedly work.

Comment: Yes it wont work at all (i think) if it wont be in the loop. It is

Comment: Ok, cool. I tested mine and it worked, but kept looking into it. Have you tried to use the_date() instead? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date. 

If neither of them work, could it be a deeper problem with date formatting in your server?

Also, if you can get the_time() in its default format, maybe you could extract the month from it:

<?php echo date('M', strtotime(get_the_date()));?>

I know it's hackish, but it could work =)